# Move svg clipPath element into common defs tag

Tags: html, svg

I am using a `clipPath` element to get an angled point on the end of an SVG. Because the visible svg needs to be responsive, the `#rightarrow` needs to be at 100% (positioned by the `use` element). I am trying to get the `clipPath#rightarrow` elements moved into the common defs to avoid duplicate id's and bloated code.

When I move the clipPaths into the common defs, the visible SVGs do not render as they should.

```html
<!-- COMMON DEFS -->
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position: absolute">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" width="6" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" patternTransform="rotate(45)">
      <line stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" y2="10"></line>
    </pattern>
    <path id="rightarrowpath" d="M-6,0 L0,10 L-6,20 L-5000,20 L-5000,0 Z"></path>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div style="width: 75%;">
  <svg width="100%" height="20px">
     <defs>
     <!-- MOVE THIS TO COMMON DEFS? -->
      <clipPath id="rightarrow">
        <use xlink:href="#rightarrowpath" x="100%"></use>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" clip-path="url(#rightarrow)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>

<div style="width: 20%;">
  <svg width="100%" height="20px">
    <defs>
      <!-- MOVE THIS TO COMMON DEFS? -->
      <clipPath id="rightarrow">
        <use xlink:href="#rightarrowpath" x="100%"></use>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#pattern)" clip-path="url(#rightarrow)"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

How can I move the clipPaths in the common defs?

Comment: id values must be unique per document. Your document is invalid as it has multiple elements with id="rightarrow"

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, that is exactly why I am asking the question. The only way I can get this svg to work correctly is the way I have it, but I want to get the clipPaths into the common defs.

Comment: Why not use markers?

Comment: @MichaelMullany, I went down the path of using markers first, but I needed to support patterns in the shape (example added to question), and I don't believe patterns are supported on lines, or polylines.

Comment: You could use a filter?